# Xamarin high memory usage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm developing an app in Xamarin, but when I show a map on a page it doubles the memory usage.
When I pop the page and open it again, it increases even more.
Now It seems to be fixed when I use the garbage collector `GC.Collect();`

I was wondering when it's the best moment to call it.
Personally I was thinking about putting it in `onAppearing()`.
But I'm not sure if it can cause problemns (like it collecting things I still need) or if this is the right way to solve the high memory usage problem.

Comment: Typically you just let the garbage collector do its thing.  Is the high memory use causing problems?

Comment: @adv12 Alright, but it's not causing problems (yet). But If the memory usage increases from 88 to 170 and everytime you reopen the view it increases even more. That may become a problem after a while if more things will be added.

Comment: Assuming you don't have an actual leak (and it sounds like you don't because GC.Collect() "fixes" things), I would expect the garbage collector to kick in on its own before the high memory use *does* cause problems.

Comment: Garbage collector may take some time before releasing memory. Also I'm not sure, but I think that operating system gives you some additional memory before running process, so that it is assigned to the process either it uses it or not. This is because requesting OS for memory takes some time. You could check if memory lowers after time, e.g. wait 1 minute and see if memory consumption drops.

Comment: The page is still opened, thats why It can't "collect" it. After waiting a few minutes it still doesn't decrease but in the debugger I can see the GC being called.

Comment: @JeroenM the page is not opened, otherwise GC.Collect wouldn't do anything to it.

Comment: `Now It seems to be fixed when I use the garbage collector GC.Collect();`, I don't think it really fixed your problem, because the memory of our program which coded by c# or java is always managed by CLR/JVM, it just accelerate CLR/JVM to process GC, but the GC won't be executed right now.  I guess there is some memory leak in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Calling GC.Collect() is something that shouldn't be done by the developer manually but sometimes necessary when it comes to Xamarin. But instead of calling it in OnAppearing I would recommend to call it in OnDisappearing instead.

If you are in the mood I would suggest that you use OnDisappering to clean-up any references or instances you don't need any more for that page. Than compare your memory-usage and see if that helps too. The reason why I prefer that way over calling GC.Collect is: GC.Collect halts every process your app runs. The more work the collecting has to do the longer your app pauses and my be feeling unresponsive and slow to the user.

Comment: `halts every process your app runs` I would suggest you look at Xamarin's `Concurrent GC` option.

Comment: I know about this option too. But in general a GC collection has implications on the application and that was what I wanted to say.